# Can a nonstatic member of a template specialize to data or function?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

GCC, Clang, ICC, and MSVC all reject this code, but I don't find any violated rule in the latest working draft of the  C++ standard.

Is the rule already in the standard, or is it in a defect report?

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename t >
struct s {
    std::conditional_t< std::is_integral< t >::value, t, void() > mem;
};

s< int > a;
s< void * > b;
```

Comment: What do you expect `void()` should evaluate to?

Comment: @StenSoft `void()` is only the type of `mem`. You can't evaluate `s<void*>::mem`, because it's the name of an unimplemented function. But that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: void() function type,usually used for the template type deduction,not define or declare a var.

Comment: @RonTang Yes, *usually*. However, [tag:language-lawyer] questions usually go outside the bounds of the usual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is invalid due to 14.3.1/3:

> If a declaration acquires a function type through a type dependent on a template-parameter and this causes a
>   declaration that does not use the syntactic form of a function declarator to have function type, the program
>   is ill-formed.

The type of the declaration here is dependent on the template parameter `t`, and therefore cannot be a function type.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Never would have looked for it there. This rule is discussing type dependence, and it applies at local scope too. IMHO it would be better placed in [temp.dep.type] §14.6.2.1.

Comment: … and, by the way, MSVC and ICC (v13.0.1) fail to diagnose it at local scope.